# Enter various data types in a text box and input them into an Object array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, wpf, object

Enter various data types in a text box and input them into an Object array

I want a way of been able to get a user to type various data types into a TextBox such as:

```
“a”, 1, 1.5, “b”
```

And then splitting these by “,” and putting them into an Object array or list. Something similar to this except with objects so im able to recognise them as either string, int etc.

```
String sample = textbox; 
String samples = sample.Split(new Char[] {','});
            foreach (var x in samples)
```

Thank You

Comment: There are three operations, creating a WPF text box, consuming the data and processing the data. Which of the three are you having an issue with? I recommend that you limit the question to one of the three; for to me it sounds like you just need help parsing the data and the WPF textbox is ancillary and not needed to define the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two step process. Step 1 is to parse a CSV line from the user and step 2 is to identify a number (I choose double) verses straight text. I prefer Regular Expressions due to their flexibility (once learned) and believe both steps can be solved using regex.

If you do a search, there are whole StackOverflow questions on the topic of identifying numbers. Your requirement appears to be a basic one, and with that understanding I will provide a basic number verses text check using a regular expression. (Note it can be expanded on to further limit possibilities):

```
List<object> items = new List<object>();
string data = "a, 1, 1.5, b";

Regex.Matches(data, "[^,]+") // Get each object without a comma over the line.
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => mt.ToString().Trim()) // Remove any whitespace (if any)
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(itm => items.Add(Regex.IsMatch(itm, "[a-zA-Z]")  ?          // Is it
                                            (object) itm :                // a string
                                            (object) Double.Parse(itm))); // a number

Console.WriteLine ( string.Join( " | ", items.Select (obj => obj.ToString())));
// Writes:
// a | 1 | 1.5 |  b

Console.WriteLine ( string.Join( ", ", items.Select (obj => obj.GetType())));
// Writes:
// System.String, System.Double, System.Double, System.String
```